# Django - How to sort a querySet.values() i.e. List of Dictionary?

Tags: python, django, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a list of dictionary through the use of values() of a querySet.

I find the list of dictionaries through:

```
set_of_pk_values = user_chartConfigurationData.objects.filter(username_chartNum_id = activeTab+"_"+username).values()
```

Since the data is sent to a jQuery DataTables. The user can click on each of the column to sort the data.

Hence, I find the "key" through order[0][column] from GET

```
keyOrder = set_of_pk_values[0].keys()[int(order_0_iColumn)]
```

keyOrder is now the key that I want to sort.

However, when I tried to use sorted with a operator:

```
set_of_pk_values = sorted(set_of_pk_values, key=operator.attrgetter(keyOrder))
```

It returns an error message: 'dict' object has no attribute 'blockName', which is actually one of the attribute of the dictionary, if you would call set_of_pk_values[0]['blockName']

Comment: What exactly is `order_0_iColumn` doing ? I mean is that a dynamically populated value? While Peter is right, i have a feeling  you might be able to get the sorted list by just order_by unless i am missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a value from a dict by key, use `operator.itemgetter` rather than `operator.attrgetter`. Though it might be worthwhile to pull the sort field out before running your `values` query and have the database do the sort instead.

Comment: Changing it to itemgetter seems to fix the error. Is there a performance improvement if I let the database sort the field first?

Comment: Generally databases are faster at sorting, yes. You shouldn't need to sort it in Python at all if you're just trying to sort by a model field.